# Find distance to ones in a binary numpy array in python

Tags: python, numpy

For a robotics project, I've used ultrasound as vision. From edge detection algorithms I've generated a binary numpy array. Now, I'm not sure what is the most cost efficient way of calculating the distance to the object.    Say I wanted to calculated the shortest distanse from a one to the top left corner? Would it be possible to use "np.where" and "dst = numpy.linalg.norm( )"?

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import ndimage
from PIL import Image


Max_filtrated = np.where(result>np.amax(result)*0.8,0,result)
Band_filtrated = np.where(Max_filtrated>np.amax(Max_filtrated)*0.11, 
1,0)

####### Define connected region and remove noise ########
mask = Band_filtrated> Band_filtrated.mean()
label_im, nb_labels = ndimage.label(mask)
sizes = ndimage.sum(mask, label_im, range(nb_labels + 1))
mean_vals = ndimage.sum(im, label_im, range(1, nb_labels + 1))
mask_size = sizes < 500
remove_pixel = mask_size[label_im]
label_im[remove_pixel] = 0
Ferdig= np.where(label_im>np.amax(label_im)*0.1,1,0)
#########################################################
```

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried doing this a different way - using the same image as I trimmed for my other answer. This time I calculate each pixel as the square of the distance from the origin and then make all black pixels in the input image inelligible for being the nearest by setting them to a big number. Then I find the smallest number in the array.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# Open image in greyscale and make into Numpy array
im = Image.open('curve.png').convert('L')
na = np.array(im)

# Make grid where every pixel is the squared distance from origin - no need to sqrt()
# This could be done outside main loop, btw
x,y = np.indices(na.shape)
dist = x*x + y*y

# Make all black pixels inelligible to be nearest
dist[np.where(na<128)] = sys.maxsize

# Find cell with smallest value, i.e. smallest distance
resultY, resultX = np.unravel_index(dist.argmin(), dist.shape)

print(f'Coordinates: [{resultY},{resultX}]')
```

**Sample Output**

```
Coordinates: [159,248]
```

**Keywords**: Python, image processing, nearest white pixel, nearest black pixel, nearest foreground pixel, nearest background pixel, Numpy

Answer (score 0):

I trimmed your image as follows - please don't post images with axes and labels if folks need to process them!

[image]

I then leverage Scipy's `cdist()` function. So, first generate a list of all the white pixels in the image, then calculate the distance from the origin at top-left to each pixel in list. Then find the minimum one.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

# Open image in greyscale and make into Numpy array
im = Image.open('curve.png').convert('L')
na = np.array(im)

# Get coordinates of white pixels
whites = np.where(na>127)

# Get distance from [0,0] to each white pixel
distances = cdist([(0,0)],np.transpose(whites))

# Index of nearest
ind = distances.argmin()

# Distance of nearest
d = distances[0,ind]

# Coords of nearest
x, y = whites[0][ind], whites[1][ind]

print(f'distance [{x},{y}] = {d}')
```

**Sample Output**

```
distance [159,248] = 294.5929394944828
```

If I draw a red circle radius=294 centred on the origin and a blue circle centred on those x,y coordinates:

[image]

**Keywords**: Python, image processing, nearest white pixel, nearest black pixel, nearest foreground pixel, nearest background pixel, Numpy, cdist()